# Is the word "various" always followed by plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Various vegetation(s) in surrounding areas of cave XXX yield(s) various species.
>
> Various vegetation(s) provide(s) food resources for various species in forest XYX.

Is the word **various** always followed by a plural noun?

Answer (score 3):

No. If you have a mass noun after *various*, you can use the singular. Of course, it has to be the right kind of mass noun; *various water* or *various sand* doesn't make much sense.

But searching the internet, you can find

> various apparatus,
>   various cannon,
>   various fruit,

where *cannon, apparatus, fruit* are (at least sometimes) mass nouns.

While *vegetation* appears to be the right type of mass noun to follow *various*, I can only find very few examples of this phrase on the internet. But I wouldn't say *various vegetations*, which sounds much worse to me; I would say *various kinds* (or *types*) *of vegetation*.

Comment: I feel like these would all be used as plural though, in the sense of verb agreement. I have to do more research on it, but it sounds wrong to me to say something like "various fruit is yellow."

Comment: Yes ... *various fruit is yellow* sounds bad.  But how about *"various fruit was displayed outside the store"*?

Comment: I prefer *varied vegetation* to *various vegetation*, but it seems [(ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=various+vegetation%2Cvaried+vegetation%2Cvariety+of+vegetation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvarious%20vegetation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvaried%20vegetation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvariety%20of%20vegetation%3B%2Cc0) that the latter has been more popular since the '70s. *Variety of vegetation* is more popular than both, though.

Comment: @PeterShor: I guess "various fruit was displayed..." does sound OK.

Comment: @sumelic & Peter "various fruit is yellow" sounds wrong **BUT** "various fruit was displayed outside the store" does sound OK; that's why (learning) English is not easy for me as a non-native speaker.

Comment: When you say "various fruit is yellow", the only reasonable meaning is "various kinds of fruit", and for "kinds of fruit", English uses the plural "fruits" (as it does for lots of kinds of mass nouns).